# Sitecore Item Web API error - Invalid item ID in query string

Tags: sitecore-services-client

I'm having an issue creating an item remotely using the item web API. Having tried several permutations of what is in the documentation, I am repeatedly seeing the following in logs:

```
ERROR Invalid item ID in query string: undefined
WARN  Context item not resolved.
WARN  Cannot resolve the scope because the item set is empty.
```

I assume it's referring to the parent item, but I get the same errors regardless if I'm using the path as below, sc_itemid, or query to the same path. Here's the code

```
  var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(
        string.Format(
               "http://sandbox.local/-/item/v1/sitecore/content/home?name={0}&template={1}&sc_database=master",
               HttpUtility.UrlEncode("testfromapi"),
               HttpUtility.UrlEncode("{54045564-B0E6-4F76-9653-C8F08812D77A}")));

        request.Headers.Add("X-Scitemwebapi-Username", "sitecore\\admin");
        request.Headers.Add("X-Scitemwebapi-Password", "b");
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentLength = 0;
```

Any obvious missteps here? TIA!

Comment: Can you use fiddler (or something similar) to see exactly how this URL is getting generated?  Maybe this URL is changing a bit from what you expect and the query string part of the URL is truly undefined when the request is made to Sitecore.

Comment: @Barbosa Yeah, tried that. Apart from the encoding of the braces, everything looks as expected -  http://sandbox.local/-/item/v1/sitecore/content/home?name=testfromapi&template=%7b54045564-B0E6-4F76-9653-C8F08812D77A%7d&sc_database=master

Comment: Obvious question, I know, but gotta ask: /sitecore/content/home is a valid path, right?  You don't happen to have an item between Content and Home?  I'm sure you don't, but again, gotta ask.

Comment: @Barbosa That's not the actual path to the item,but yes the path I'm using is indeed valid. I also tried using the sc_itemid parameter to pass in the ID of the item but got same error.

Comment: I realize the error you're getting doesn't suggest a security issue but just to rule that out, can you take a look at the security settings described in the guide and try loosing up the security a bit to see if it helps?  Here's the guide - https://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20Item%20Web%20API/SitecoreItemWebApi12/Documentation.aspx

Comment: Appreciate all the replies @Barbosa ! Yep, I've got

itemwebapi.mode="StandardSecurity"         itemwebapi.access="ReadWrite"
itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess="true"